# How can I use GPU for running a tflite model (*.tflite) using tf.lite.Interpreter (in python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, interpreter, tensorflow-lite

I have converted a tensorflow inference graph to tflite model file (*.tflite), according to instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert.

I tested the tflite model on my GPU server, which has 4 Nvidia TITAN GPUs. I used the tf.lite.Interpreter to load and run tflite model file.

It works as the former tensorflow graph, however, the problem is that the inference became too slow. When I checked out the reason, I found that the GPU utilization is simply 0% when tf.lite.Interpreter is running.

Is there any method that I can run tf.lite.Interpreter with GPU support?

Comment: Did you install tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: Yes, I checked that GPUs are being used in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34536

CPU is kind of good enough for tflite, especially multicore.

nvidia GPU likely not updated for tflite, which is for mobile GPU platform.